# log4j2 lookup websphere environment variable

Tags: java, log4j, websphere, log4j2, websphere-8

I'm using log4j2 (version 2.10.0) together with IBM Websphere 8.5.5.12.
The problem is that the Websphere environment variable in my log4j2.properties is not getting resolved. I've tried a few things like

```
property.filename = $${sys:Test}/Test.log
property.filename = ${env:Test}/Test.log
```

But whatever i try, it is not resolving "Test". Anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the variable created at the right resource scope, accessible by your JVM, this can be fixed by adding a JVM custom property with the same name as the Websphere environment variable and value as given below:

```
Steps : In WAS Admin console, Go to 
    WebSphere application servers > 
        Server_name > 
            Java and Process Management (under Server Infrastructure)> 
                Process definition > 
                    Java Virtual Machine (under Additional Properties)> 
                        Custom properties
Click on New and enter below details : 
    Name  : Test
    Value : ${Test}
Apply and save the changes.
```

Restart the JVM and retest !

**EDIT :** As mentioned in the comment below, after adding the JVM custom property, the variable can be directly accessed from log4j file, as given below:

```
property.filename = ${Test}/Test.log
```

Comment: That's tha part that is working. The problem is that the variable in my log4j2.properties file isnt resolved to the environment variable in websphere

Comment: If you have set the JVM custom property, then you can access the variable directly in log4j, as given below
property.filename = ${Test}/Test.log

Comment: a few things, 1st I used environment->websphere Variables to define the variable. (not sure if thats the right one). 2nd tried it your way but no result either. 3rd: Value i filled with a path

Comment: when I define the variable your way and I use the prefix sys: in the properties file it works. lets see if it is defined the same way on the real server in stead of local